# Can you fold functions by default in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings, fold

I want to fold all the functions in my .ts file in visual studio code.
Is this possible to set this default by startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it: `ctrl+k+à` and just open the class. Now all functions are folded.